# Wordpress Podio Form embedded error

Tags: wordpress, forms, podio

I try to embed my Podio Form in to this wordpress page however it's just show `/ < ![CDATA[ // < ![CDATA[ //` as in the picture above
[image]

Here is the code that I used:

```
[av_textblock size='' font_color='' color='']
[:vi]
[/av_textblock]

[av_codeblock wrapper_element='' wrapper_element_attributes='' custom_class='']
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->
<script src="https://podio.com/webforms/15016309/1006763.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// < ![CDATA[
// < ![CDATA[ _podioWebForm.render("1006763")
// ]]></script>
<noscript>
<a href="https://podio.com/webforms/15016309/1006763" target="_blank">Please fill out the form</a>
</noscript>
<div class="podio-webform-container">A webform by <a class="podio-webform-inner" href="https://company.podio.com/project-management-software">Podio</a></div>
<!-- END Podio web form -->
[/av_codeblock]

[av_textblock size='' font_color='' color='']
[:en]
[/av_textblock]

[av_codeblock wrapper_element='' wrapper_element_attributes='' custom_class='']
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->

// < ![CDATA[ // < ![CDATA[ //

<!-- END Podio web form -->
[/av_codeblock]

[av_textblock size='' font_color='' color='']
[:]
[/av_textblock]
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of WordPress plugin. Can you share the name of it?

Also, are you pasting this block in the "Visual" tab or the "Text" tab? This source code won't work if you paste it into the "Visual" editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the form render function commented out and prefixed with `< ![CDATA[`

You also have it wrapped with `[av_codeblock wrapper_element='' wrapper_element_attributes='' custom_class='']` which I'm not sure what that even is; but it might cause rendering issues.

```html
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->
<script src="https://podio.com/webforms/12345/6789.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _podioWebForm.render("6789")
</script>
<noscript>
  <a href="https://podio.com/webforms/11234/6789" target="_blank">Please fill out the form</a>
</noscript>
<div class="podio-webform-container">
  Get your <a href="https://podio.com" class="podio-webform-inner" rel="nofollow">free webform</a> from Podio
</div>
<!-- END Podio web form -->
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code snippet, the format of the webform embed code looks different from what we would expect to be generated by Podio.  For example, if I export a webform on a demo app the code looks like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->
<script src="https://podio.com/webforms/12345678/1234567.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _podioWebForm.render("1234567")
</script>
<noscript>
  <a href="https://podio.com/webforms/12345678/1234567" target="_blank">Please fill out the form</a>
</noscript>
  <div class="podio-webform-container">
  Get your <a href="https://podio.com" class="podio-webform-inner" rel="nofollow">free webform</a> from Podio
  </div>
<!-- END Podio web form -->
```

As a starting point, please navigate to your App in Podio, select the wrench icon from the top left, and the select `Webform`.  Enter the domain of your website in the provided field, and copy and paste the provided embed code directly into your Wordpress HTML.  [Here if a helpful video that walks through this process.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL1gh5mHsxM)